Firebase Firestore Update Operation Overwrites Data Incorrectly
I’m facing an issue with my Firestore update operation where data from one user occasionally overwrites data from another user.
Issue Breakdown:

Firebase Authentication using signInWithEmailAndPassword.
Users stored in Firestore with unique user IDs.
Dashboard displays all users, allowing them to be updated.
Issue: Sometimes, when updating one user's data, it overwrites another user’s entry in Firestore.

Example

User A (ID dv6d...) and User B (ID pzF1...).
When updating User B, User A’s data sometimes gets overwritten, causing User A’s data to be lost.

See the below images to get the context

Data of User A (ID dv6d...)

Data of User B (ID pz...) this got overwritten by user A's data

File to display all the users
function User() {
  const { deleteData, getData } = useAdmin();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState(null);
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const resultsPerPage = 10;

  const handleSelectedUser = (user) => {
    setSelectedUser(user);
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadUserData = async () => {
      await getData("Users", setUserData);
    };
    loadUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            <tr>
              <TableCell>Full Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Email</TableCell>
              //similar other entries
            </tr>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {userData.slice((page - 1) * resultsPerPage, page * resultsPerPage).map((user, i) => (
              <TableRow key={i}>
                <TableCell>{user?.fullName}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{user?.email}</TableCell>              
                <TableCell>
                  <Button onClick={() => handleSelectedUser(user)}>Edit</Button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>

      {selectedUser && (
        <EditUser
          user={selectedUser}
          isModalOpen={isModalOpen}
          closeModal={() => setIsModalOpen(false)}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}


Editing User Data (EditUser Component)
export const EditUser = ({ user, isModalOpen, closeModal }) => {
  const [updatedData, setUpdatedData] = useState({ ...user });
  const { updateData } = useAdmin();

  const handleSave = async () => {
    await updateData(user?.id, "Users", updatedData, setLoading);
    closeModal();
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUpdatedData({ ...updatedData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={closeModal}>
      <ModalHeader>Edit User</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        <Input
          name="fullName"
          defaultValue={user?.fullName}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="email"
          defaultValue={user?.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
       
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button onClick={handleSave}>Save</Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
  );
};

AdminContext (React Context for State Management)
// removed necessary imports for better readability 
const AdminContext = createContext();

export const useAdmin = () => useContext(AdminContext);

export const AdminProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const updateData = async (docId, dbName, updatedData, setLoading) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const docRef = doc(db, dbName, docId);

      await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
        const docSnapshot = await transaction.get(docRef);

        if (!docSnapshot.exists()) {
          throw new Error("Document does not exist!");
        }

        const { id, ...dataWithoutId } = updatedData;

        // Perform the update within the transaction
        transaction.update(docRef, dataWithoutId);
      });

      toastSuccess(`${dbName} Updated Successfully`);
    } catch (error) {
      toastError(error.message);
      setError(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const getData = useCallback(async (dbName, setloading, setData) => {
    setloading(true);
    try {
      const data = [];
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, dbName));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      });
      setData(data);
      setloading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      toastError(error.message);
      setError(error.message);
      setloading(false);
    }
  }, []);

const value = {
      updateData,
      getData
    };

  return (
    <AdminContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AdminContext.Provider>
  );
};



What exactly are you expecting your code to do that's different than what you observe?  Please edit the question to be clear.  I suggest also removing all irrelevant code and focus on that which performs the database changes so we can better see what the problem is.

Oof... while I immediately suspect that you're not handling the asynchronous nature of useState (see this for example) somewhere, it is hard to find the exact place that happens based on what you shared. As Doug said, this is really far from a minimal repro - and it's incomplete (e.g. useAdmin is missing). I recommend reading How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example, creating a repro from scratch based on that, and then sharing that here.

Sorry for confusion, I'll create a replit for this and will share it.

If you encounter problems, it's best to create a MCVE when posting a question. You posted more than 400 (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's way too much code for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read how to ask a question.

@AlexMamo
I have removed unnecessary lines of code and imports as well to make the code readable, please check this out and let me know if it is still confusing.
